# EJB 3.1 Security Authorization while using CDI

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, cdi, ejb-3.1

In EJB, for security authentication and authorization I find a common method using jndi as follows,

```
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
Context ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
Object ref = jndiContext.lookup("SecureBean/remote");
SecureRemoteBusiness remote = (SecureRemoteBusiness)ref;
```

Question: I would like to know if there are any methods to achieve this while using DI possibly without using any external CDI frameworks.  If the only choice is using external CDI frameworks, kindly provide me an example or a reference.

Comment: What app server are you using? I am afraid you will have to go for server specific api for remote EJB authentication if you want something different to what you have in your example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am using Glassfish.  So, is authentication through JNDI is the best possible mechanism available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in any of the Java EE specs that really address the full authentication and authorization hole, that's the reason things like Spring Security, Apache Shiro, JBoss Picketlink, etc. exist.

As for your question, no, there is not any way to achieve this with DI without using an external framework. Anything that you will find will be proprietary to the server, as Gonzalo Garcia Lasurtegui mentioned.

Comment: There is one more thing I learnt.  When using the security authentication features of the AS through "j_security_check" with proper configurations in web.xml, by default your web-tier session details are maintained and propagated to the application-tier during lookups or calls.  So, you do not have to bother about passing security credentials in JNDI lookups.  The best thing is that CDI can also be used without any restrictions while all the security credentials are passed on seamlessly :-)